# Enable CORS in Web API , But Not in entire MVC 5 project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2

Is it possible to Enable CORS in Web API ,  But Not in entire mvc project  that has both (MVC5 + Web API 2) ?

currently i am using separate  projects for WEB API 2 and MVC  to enable CORS only in WEB API.

If Possible, Then How ?

Comment: This article looks to only mention WebAPI http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api

Comment: Thanks @coulton. adding EnableCors at controller level is working .

Comment: Great to hear.  I'll post it as an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following tutorial appears to be specific to WebAPI 2 and doesn't mention anything about ASP.NET MVC:

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api